# Jquery hide Dropdown if all option value are empty

Tags: jquery

How can it hide a listbox if all option values are empty, i tried to do this , but it's not working

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){

    if($('#mylistbox').val().length === '') {
        $('#mylistbox').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a selector that matches options with non-empty values, and get the length of the collection.

```
if ($("#mylistbox option[value!='']").length == 0) {
    $("#mylistbox").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. This is not working. What I mean is if all option values in my listbox are empties.

<select id="mylistbox" size="3" name="mylistbox">
  <option value="">Country</option>
  <option value="">City</option>
  <option value="">State</option>
</select>

Answer (score 2):

You might need to edit it!

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
   if($('#mylistbox').val().length == 0) { // int value
     $('#mylistbox').hide();
   }
});
```

Because `''` would be used with the `val()` method. You can use `0` which is int, and would be used to check against the length of the value.

So, if you want to use the `val()` method, then use

```
if ($('#mylistbox').val() === '') {
   // code here...
}
```

But if you want to use, the `length` property of the element. Then use

```
if ($('#mylistbox').val().length == 0) {
  // code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Afzaal. This is not working . If all option values in my listbox are empties.

<select id="mylistbox" size="3" name="mylistbox">
  <option value="">Country</option>
  <option value="">City</option>
  <option value="">State</option>
</select>